# How to fatch relations from SupabaseBD on budibase app?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, budibase

I create a DB(Supabase) and then I made tables on Supabase PostgreSQL DB and build their relations. Now we connect DB to budibase app.

Now we get data from DB but when we fetch data from DB. It Creates connections but it would not create relations between tables. Also, change column dataType.
[Screen Short of Supabase DB Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M1m0.png)

[Screen Short of Budibase where we fetch DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1U1l.png)